# Probability of drawing objects: Combinations vs Permutations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> A bag contains 5 red and 3 blue balls. If 3 balls are drawn at random without replacement the probability of getting exactly one red ball is

**Attempt 1**
$$
P(\text{exactly 1 red ball})=\frac{^5C_1 \cdot ^3C_2}{^8C_3}=\frac{5 \cdot 3}{\frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}}=\frac{5 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}=\frac{15}{56}
$$
**Attempt 2**
\begin{align*}
P(\text{exactly 1 red ball}) & = P(RBB)+P(BRB)+P(BBR)\\
& =\frac{5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}+\frac{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 2}{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}+\frac{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 5}{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}\\
& =3 \cdot \frac{5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}\\
& =\frac{15}{56}
\end{align*}
Though I get same result in both methods, I think first method uses combinations(order does not matter) and second uses permutation(order matters), how can I differentiate the two ?

Comment: The number of combinations is literally the number of permutations, such that the ordering of elements does not matter.

Comment: @ab123 in method 1, I think we are not considering order, ie. whether u take red ball in the 1st or 2nd or 3rd attempt does not matter, right?. But in method 2, i guess we are taking order in to account.

Comment: By taking order into account, you are multiplying both the numerator and denominator in the first approach by the $3!$ ways in which you can select the three balls in order, which is why the results are equal.

Comment: There are two correct chains of thought. Why are you surprised that the result is the same? It's the same as multiplying $321\cdot567$ "from the right" or "from the left".

Comment: @ChristianBlatter irrespective of whether the question demands to consider order or not, the probability is the same, thats why it gives the same result, right ?

Comment: Will the answer be the same if all the balls are identical except for color? For example, in how many ways can you pick one red ball out of the 5 red balls? Only one way right?

Comment: @sku yea. thats how we differentiate combinations and permutations right. But, when it comes to finding probability as the example i mentioned, it seems that order matters or not does not change probability right ?

Comment: I think, method 1 should be like, $P=\frac{^5C_1.^3C_2\cdot3!}{^8C_3\cdot3!}=\frac{15}{56}$ as we consider order, right ?. But, the resulting probability 'd be the same if we do not consider order, right ?

Answer (score 2):

In Attempt 1 the underlying assumption is that you have a random mechanism selecting a $3$-element subset from a given $8$-element set, whereby all $3$-element subsets are equiprobable. You then count the number of favorable $3$-element subsets.

In Attempt 2 the underlying assumption is that you have a random mechanism selecting an element from a given finite set, whereby all elements are equiprobable, and you apply this mechanism three times. Finally you compute the probability of the desired outcome.

The reason that you obtain the same result in both cases is the following: Both mechanisms select (in one, resp., in three steps) a $3$-element subset of the given $8$-element set, uniformly over all ${8\choose3}$ such subsets.The first mechanism does so by its specification, and the second "by symmetry".